# Unit Testing a Login in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, tdd

I'm very new to TDD and I'm having trouble with one of my unit tests. I just can't seem to understand what to do next. :( I'm trying to unit test a service of mine called AccountService and I'm testing a method called DoLogin(username, password). Here's some example code:

```
    [Test]
    public void User_With_Correct_Username_And_Pass_Should_Login_Successfully()
    {
        // Arrange
        var accountService = new AccountService();

        // Act
        bool result = accountService.DoLogin("test", "test");

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
      public bool DoLogin(string username, string password)
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return false;

        return true;
      }
    }
```

So this test pasts but now what do I do?! How do I really test if a valid login occured? Do I need to implement an integration test and test the login against a real or in-memory DB? Sorry if I'm doing things totally incorrect. I really hope one day to get this TDD stuff down. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your experience is very similar to mine starting out. While I am sold on TDD and wouldn't do thing any differently, I certainly understand your confusion. It is important to remember that TDD is a design philosophy. That being said, I think I can help to clear up some of your frustrations.

1. Start by thinking about what you are trying to accomplish, not on an individual test level, but what is it you are trying to do. If your task (user story) involves grabbing some credentials and attempting to authenticate the current user based on those credentials, then start from there and work your way down. *You seem to be heading in this direction, only getting stuck on the next steps*
2. When working on an individual test, think of it in terms of [expected behavior](http://behaviour-driven.org/) instead of just verifying some inputs and outputs. Think of yourself as using this component, and simply write a line of code the way you want it to be written. Let this part help to drive the interface/contract of your service. You have to ask yourself the question, "If I were to call this method, how would I know it worked? What would I expect it to do?" This will determine what kind of assertions you need to make.
3. Determine what your external dependencies are, and [utilize abstractions instead](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf) (dependency inversion principle). If these dependencies are something you care about as part of your behavior verification, then use [dependency injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) so you can use a [mock](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) in your test.
4. Always, always, always follow this order [Write your test, watch it fail, code to pass, refactor]. **LEARN FROM MY MISTAKES!!!** Trust me, this is non-negotiable. Otherwise, you are liable to blame your problems on TDD when it isn't being employed properly.

Ok, so putting this all together with your example, and some nicely provided [test cases from lance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953257/unit-testing-a-login-in-asp-net/953365#953365), we could do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldAuthenticateValidUser()
{
    IMyMockDa mockDa = new MockDataAccess();
    var service = new AuthenticationService(mockDa);

    mockDa.AddUser("Name", "Password");

    Assert.IsTrue(service.DoLogin("Name", "Password"));

    //Ensure data access layer was used
    Assert.IsTrue(mockDa.GetUserFromDBWasCalled);
}

[Test]
public void ShouldNotAuthenticateUserWithInvalidPassword()
{
    IMyMockDa mockDa = new MockDataAccess();
    var service = new AuthenticationService(mockDa);

    mockDa.AddUser("Name", "Password");

    Assert.IsFalse(service.DoLogin("Name", "BadPassword"));

    //Ensure data access layer was used
    Assert.IsTrue(mockDa.GetUserFromDBWasCalled);
}
```

Ok, so there is a lot going on there, and perhaps a lot to research. However, you can begin to see how it is possible to do thorough testing by using better design. In the examples above, it is important to note that the Mock Object is custom rolled, but you don't have to go through all this pain. There are many Mocking Frameworks out there. For instance using [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx), your test would look like this:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldAuthenticateValidUser()
{
    var mockRepo = new MockRepository();
    var mockDa = mockRepo.DynamicMock<IMyMockDa>();

    var service = new AuthenticationService(mockDa);

    using(mockRepo.Record())
    {
        //I realize this is a terrible method and should not exist if you
        // care about security, but for demonstration purposes...
        Expect.Call(mockDa.GetPassword("User")).Return("Password");
    }
    using(mockRepo.Playback())
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(service.DoLogin("User", "Password"));
    }
}
```

Get used to doing things the manual way first so you understand the concepts, and then move on to using a framework. Whew! Lots of info, but as you can see, TDD is an entire design philosophy. It will however, result in cleaner code, better design, and fewer bugs.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to write this! I really appreciate it. You said lots of good stuff and it will probably take me awhile to grasp everything. You're right that I have to get used thinking differently when doing TDD. Hopefully my confusion some day will pass, but that will just take time. Thanks again!

Comment: It took a long time before I had that "Ah Ha" moment, but now I am totally converted. I would encourage you to check out another SO post I made about TDD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106800/unit-testing-guidelines/106813#106813

Comment: The wonky rendering that you saw is a known bug with old answers - you can fix this for any answer (not just your own) by submitting any edit, which forces the answer to be re-rendered. This also explains why it looks fine when you first bring up the editor. I touched up the formatting here, but you can also submit a stub edit and undo it and it will still force the answer to re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Pass what you know to be valid and invalid credentials to DoLogin, and then compare the results to what you expect.  Try to imagine every possible (read: reasonable) combination/input of the "username" and "password" parameters the user will provide, and create a test for each.

If your DoLogin business logic is to be believed, we're defining a "valid" username (and a "valid" password) to be anything that's populated.  Fair enough, for discussion's sake.

Some simple tests come to mind:

```
Login_With_Null_UserName_Fails()
Login_With_Populated_UserName_Succeeds()
Login_With_Empty_UserName_Fails()
Login_With_Null_Password_Fails()
Login_With_Populated_Password_Succeeds()
Login_With_Empty_Password_Fails()
```

Or, consider combinations:

```
Login_With_Null_UserName_And_Populated_Password_Fails()
Login_With_Populated_UserName_And_Populated_Password_Succeeds()
Login_With_Empty_UserName_And_Null_Password_Fails()
etc
etc
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. So after I'm done exhausting my test list for DoLogin what is my next step? Do I then really test the login against a DB?

Comment: If you think there's sufficient risk in your sending parameters to and getting the correct results back from your stored procedures, sure!

Testing helps lower risk and improve code.  I recommend tests anywhere you reasonably anticipate either opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a test that an invalid username or invalid password causes DoLogin() to fail.

Given the name of the function, (DoLogin() rather then CheckLogin()) I'd think the function should have some side effect as well.  The test should verify that side affect.  Really need to clarify what that is before someone can clarify how it should be verified.