# Creating easy to maintain tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, bdd

During a proposal about implementing unit tests for our projects, my manager argued that it could be more expensive to create unit tests since you will be maintaining two sets of code. His argument is whenever there is a change in requirement/functionality, the unit tests can be obsolete, hence the developers should update the tests in order to pass the automated build. He said that it can be inconvenient for the developers since their coding time might be reduced and spent fixing the tests.

The reason I wanted to implement unit tests is to minimize bug occurence especially the critical ones before the codes are turned to validation team for functional test. I also believe that the cost of creating unit tests can be recovered by having better quality systems.

Right now, his challenge to me is to create easy to maintain tests that would be easy to modify or if possible tests that will not break easily. I am using xUnit testing frameworks like JUnit and mocking frameworks like mockito and powermock to help in testing.

I'm looking for tips and techniques on how to write easy to maintain tests or how to avoid brittle test. Are there other tools which can come handy in creating such tests. I'm writing codes in Java and C++. Thanks.

Comment: "it could be more expensive to create unit tests since you will be maintaining two sets of code" --- lol. And if you don't have tests and you test all the application features *manually* after even a small change - it takes even more time.

Comment: There is no silver bullet - you get how to write maintainable tests with practice, after some period of writing non-maintainable tests (yes, learning is when you make mistake and *continuously* improve your skills)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're facing a difference in culture - your manager fears the potential time sink that testing provides. It is a known fact that a TDD/BDD process is more expensive up-front - but as time goes on you start to reap the rewards as "changing just this one isolated thing..." - no longer throws up painful/embarrassing/**costly** bugs.

My suggestion is that you do some research and put together a document that tries to sell the process to your manager, putting forwards a business case based on what has happened in your business already that could/would have been solved with a solid test suite.

There is one book that goes into TDD better than any website, article etc I've ever seen. I'd highly recommend it as reading for anyone wanting to practise TDD/BDD/OOP: 
http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/ (I don't earn any money from linking this! - but it is a superb addition to my desk!).

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it is almost impossible to truly convince a "Unit Testing Skeptic".

My advice: Start adding tests and increase coverage on a selection of the most important and frequently changing parts of your product. Do this on your own time, and possibly with an "accomplice", and time your work.

After that, show the skeptics examples of regression bugs caught by these tests, and how your time spent was actually worth it. If you succeed in doing so, management will see value in devoting resources for unit tests.

As per the technical challenge, I agree with other answers here that practice makes perfect, but there are some guidelines that could help you:

- Test only one thing per test. If you have 100 tests that assert the same condition, when this condition changes, you'll have to update 100 tests.
- If your "Class Under Test" is huge, with a ton of logic in it, it will be very hard to test it. Try to refactor your classes into small, coherent units of logic. When one of these units will change, the number of broken tests will be relatively small.
- Test your public interface, not implementation details. This will allow developers to fix bugs, improve performance, and refactor, with minimal effect on tests.

There are many [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106800/unit-testing-guidelines) [guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/unittesting.html) on the first page of Google's "unit testing guidelines", and you can read [The Art Of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/) for an extensive coverage on writing good unit tests.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Whether you write unit tests or not should not concern your management. What usually matters is that functionality is implemented fast and with no bugs. How you achieve it is up to you, developers; unit testing is just one method. It works best for loosely coupled code where you can easily mock out dependencies.

But writing good unit tests is not just about decision to write them, or tools you use, it is mostly about experience which you can gain only by practicing. There are no simple recipes that will let you write good unit tests, as there are no for code. If you just force people with no experience to write unit tests, surely productivity will slump, and there will be no apparent benefits. Ultimately, you should be writing unit tests because you believe it helps you, not because someone else thinks it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the unit tests should test implementation and not functionality. So if the developers refactor the code, nothing should change with the unit tests because they aren't testing the internals, just the results.

Of course, if you change the interface or the behavior drastically, of course the tests will change, but then you will want to be testing the new code ANYWAY, so you'd still be writing tests.

Long story short, there is a lot of research out there that a good test suite saves time in the long run by a huge margin.

Comment: I think the phrase "The answer is that the unit tests should test implementation and not functionality." is a bit confusing. I'd phrase it in a way like "Unit tests should test unit behavior from unit client's point of view, they should not test the implementation details."

Answer (score 0):

Having unified **test-datafactories** may reduce maintanance cost if system-under-test changes.

tests offten have similar test-setups with only small variations.

when i started unittesting i used copy&paste to create a new test from an existing.

every test had a long test-setup.

after changes in the system-under-test i had to update many tests.

today i use test-datafactories where only the difference to the standard is assigned.

example

```
  void customerUnder18ShouldNotbeGrantedAccess() {
      // Arrange
      Customer customer = TestdataFactory.CreateStandardCustomer();
      customer.setAge(16);

      // Act...
      // Assert ..
  }
```

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161817/9007) are more usefull tips.